# Back up to Dropbox using ZIP instead of TGZ via PHP

Tags: php

I found this PHP code. It backs up files and databased from your website to dropbox.

```
<?php

// Set the timezone so filenames are correct
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// Dropbox username/password
$dropbox_email='dropbox@dropbox.com';
$dropbox_pass='password';

// MySQL username/password/db name
$mysql_database='mysql_database';
$mysql_username='mysql_username';
$mysql_password='password';

// Filenames for backup files
$backup_dbname = "database_" . date("Y.m.d-H.i.s_l") . '.sql.gz';
$backup_files = "files_" . date("Y.m.d-h.i.s_l") . '.tgz';

// File to backup
$siteroot = "/site/home/public_html/";

// Backup database, obviously you can tweak the mysqldump switches
// Backup is GZipped.
system("mysqldump -h localhost -u $mysql_username --password=$mysql_password $mysql_database --complete-insert | gzip > $backup_dbname");

// Backup all files in public_html apart from the gz
system("tar -czvf $backup_files $siteroot");

include("DropboxUploader.php");

$uploader = new DropboxUploader($dropbox_email, $dropbox_pass);
$uploader->upload($backup_files,'Backup/Files/');
$uploader->upload($backup_dbname,'Backup/Database/');

system("rm $backup_files");
system("rm $backup_dbname");

?>
```

I want to back up the files $backup_files = "files_" . date("Y.m.d-h.i.s_l") . '.tgz'; to zip not tgz. When I repaced 'tgz' with 'zip' the zip file didn't open. I also tried to add '$createZip = new createZip;' but it didn't create the zip file at all.

I prefer zip instead of tgz for my situation please.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site where you present the code you found and ask others to modify it on your behalf. We would be happy to help if you were interested in modifying it yourself and had a specific question regarding that. Please see the FAQ and especially [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: That is what I did in my original question. I tried modifying it myself to use zip intstead of tgz.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("tar -czvf $backup_files $siteroot");
```

--> this command does the actual archiving using the Linux 'tar' command. system() is a function which can run these external binaries from within php. What you have to do is replace this particular call to 'tar' with something calling 'zip' - if that program exists on the machine in question.

You can find examples of how 'zip' is called on Linux here:
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_zipx.htm

Johan